# How to deploy a dynamic object using CloudDeploy

Tags: cloud-deploy

I want to deploy a dynamic object by CloudDeploy,which can update by the time interval, i check the help doc and find the method:
[image]
So i try this method but it seems not work as expected,the displayed result is fixed when i open the link,here is the code:

```
CloudDeploy[Dynamic[RandomReal[],UpdateInterval -> 1], Permissions -> "Public"]
# CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/b67a721a-25b2-449f-add3-\d257ecbbaa4b"]
```

Is there anybody can help me?thanks.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. `UpdateInterval` is not yet supported in Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: @dsingh thanks！